# How to resolve a NamingException that's only thrown when running application

Tags: java, ejb-2.x, jboss-4.0.x

i got error:

> javax.naming.NamingException: Could not dereference object [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:BranchProcessorLocal not bound]

in my EJB-Hibernet project

I am using jboss-4.0.2, NetBeans-6.8, JavaEE 5

Project is build successfully in NetBeans but when i try to deploy it and run application i got above error.

I had put `.ear` files into lib directory also.

How do I resolve this exception?

Comment: It says that BranchProcessorLocal does not exist. Have you tried accessing the Application Server through JMX to confirm that it does exist. Who creates it?

Comment: hi Luciano, Actually I am totally new in Hibernet and EJB. it is ready made project, code provided by client and I am trying to run this so please guide briefly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Luciano suggested, check that you really have BranchProcessorLocal bound in JNDI. You can find it in JMX Console (WUI app that ships with JBoss - http://server:port/jmx-console). Use ObjectName filter on top right and search for **jboss:service=JNDIView**. On the bean that is found, execute list method. You'll get list of all names in JNDI. If the BranchProcessorLocal  is not there, then you have incorrect implementation or deployment, but it is hard to guess, because options are numerous.

Comment: hi Luciono thanks for replay i had done as u suggest and i got "java: Namespace" and "Global JNDI Namespace " in that page and its description... any idea what is an error?

Comment: The question is whether there is `BranchProcessorLocal` in that listing. This is, whether your EJB component is bound to JNDI. If it not, then you most probably have incorrectly annotated your EJB.

Comment: hi Martin Thanks..the problem is solved now that was project deployment error, now this all beans are listing..:)